# Why does binary npm file have two checks

Tags: node.js, npm

Every binary inside `node_modules/.bin` have the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

# check if there is node executable in the same directory as this binary
if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../angular-cli/bin/ng" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../angular-cli/bin/ng" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

I sort of understand what this code is doing (comments are mine), but is there anywhere an explanation why they are here (some use cases)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for the `node` binary in the same directory is for the cases when this module was installed globally and has an executable file in the same place as Node. It makes sure that it uses the same `node` for which it was installed, even if you have some other Node in your PATH.

The `else` branch uses just `node` which means the same binary as you get by typing:

```
which node
```

which is the first `node` in one of the directories in the `PATH` environment variable.

The problem with installing Node scripts is that they have to have some shebang line. People usually use `#!/usr/bin/env node` to run whatever `node` you have in PATH. But it may be a different `node` (possibly incompatible) than the one that was actually used to install that script.

Incidentally, that is one of the reasons why I prefer installing Node from sources than from the binary packages, because otherwise my `npm` script can run the wrong `node` if I have multiple versions installed. See [my tutorial](https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a) on Node installation for details.

Thye Cygwin test checks if the output of the `uname` command contains the word CYGWIN and in that case uses a Cygwin-specific path resolution using `cygpath -w "$basedir"`. Cygwin is a collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows - see: https://www.cygwin.com/ - and it does some path translation to make scripts written for Unix and Linux work on Windows. For Linux the output of `uname` is just `Linux`. On Cygwin it contains `CYGWIN`.

Comment: thanks, _when this module was installed globally and has an executable file in the same place as Node_ - but the script assumes that you run the executable that is placed directly in the folder with node, not the one inside `node_modules/.bin`, correct? and what about the check with `uname`?

Comment: any comment on the check with `uname`?

Comment: @Maximus I added info on the `uname` check. See my updated answer.

Comment: got it, thanks for your comments. I use git-bash on windows and `uname` ouputs `MINGW64_NT-10.0`

Comment: _if I have multiple versions installed_ - do you not use `nvm`?